# Generate Ethereum Address

Tags: go-ethereum, android

I have used Geth.aar library for generating ethereum address from 24 word seed.

But every time I got new address.

I need same address every time.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you giving the library the 24 words every time, or are you using the library to create 24 random words?

Comment: I'm giving 24 words seed every time.

Comment: Can you put here a link to the library? Perhaps it doesn't have support for HD wallets.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile%3A-Introduction

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you **cannot** the generate the same key (Mnemonic seed of words) more than once.

To quote [Nick](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5em2mk/_/dadlw7e)

> There are 2<sup>160</sup> Ethereum addresses, so you'd have to generate an average of 2<sup>80</sup> private keys before you randomly generated two identical ones (or two different private keys that result in the same address).

Generation of private keys is purposefully designed to be random in a way that no other person can derive it. i.e they are called "private" for security reasons.

Your best bet is to generate the key once & store  it in a database or write it to a text file of some sort.

Then use that(the stored key) to continuously generate the same address from there.

You may also use [ethaddress.org](https://github.com/ryepdx/ethaddress.org) to generate your private keys. It's easier to use than Geth IMHO

Comment: Sounds like OP is attempting to deterministically get an address using a seed; that should always yield the same family of addresses (and is the whole point of using a seed).